# RESTeasy ContainerRequestFilter does not contain user info when deployed to tomcat (container managed authentication)

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy

I use resteasy-core with resteasy-servlet-initializer, version "4.5.2.Final".
The Application class registers "new ACLContainerRequestFilter()" via getSingletons():

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class Services extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return Sets.newHashSet(... , new ACLContainerRequestFilter());
  }
```

In the filter, I'd like to check the security context:

```
public class ACLContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  ...

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    SecurityContext sc = requestContext.getSecurityContext();
    if (sc == null || sc.getUserPrincipal() == null)
      throw new NotAuthorizedException("Requests need to be authenticated");
    if (sc.isUserInRole(role))
      ...
```

When I deploy to Jetty 9.4.27, everything works fine. I can configure container managed security, check roles in the filter etc.

When I deploy the WAR to Tomcat 9.0.31, sc.getUserPrincipal() returns null, sc.isUserInRole(...) is always false. Tomcat container managed security is setup correctly (checked via the manager/html application).

Any ideas / pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Seems like Tomcat sets the security context "on-demand". Once I added the following web.xml, calls to sc.getUserPrincipal() and sc.isUserInRole(...) worked as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```